# How to keep Android Text-to-Speech object bound to TTS engine after switching Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, text-to-speech

I have TTS object in my Activity. It is bound to speech engine and ready to talk. Then I start other Activity (for result). It makes some user interaction and gives back the result. But when I try to use this TTS it says

> "[*some TTS method name*] failed: not bound to TTS engine"

and there is no speech whatsoever. Is there any way to 'reconnect to engine'?

I'd appreciate if anyone could help me.
Thanks!

Comment: Post the code you are using to connect to the engine. Just launching another activity shouldn't necessarily cause this to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot think of an easy way.

I complicated way to do it would be to use a `Service` which holds the TTS instance.

Or just re-create a new `TextToSpeech` in the result `Activity`. Are you seeing significant slowness if you do this?

Comment: I wanted to have the text read right after leaving the secondary Activity. But since the first TextToSpeech is not much of a use, I'll have to instantiate another one and wait for it to initialize. I cannot see another way so far.

Comment: As I said in my comment to your question, there isn't any reason you can't do this. If you post some code maybe we can help you.